# Expected 2d array but got scalar array instead

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, spyder, data-science

I am getting this error

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead: array=6.5.
>   Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a
>   single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

while executing this code

```
# SVR

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVR

# Load dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

# Fitting the SVR to the data set
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf', gamma = 'auto')
regressor.fit(X, y)

# Predicting a new result 
y_pred = regressor.predict(6.5)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be aware that it does not help to put "Please help out" in the title or even in the question. Everyone posting here wants help in some way. Please also read the instructions you get while entering your question: code should be formatted with the corresponding toolbar button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how SVM works. Your trainig data is a matrix of shape `(n_samples, n_features)`. That means, your SVM operates in feature space of `n_features` dimensions. Hence, it cannot predict a value for a scalar input, unless `n_features` is 1. You can only predict values for vectors of dimension `n_features`. So, if your data set has 5 columns, you can predict values for an arbitrary row-vector of 5 columns. See the below example.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR

# Data: 200 instances of 5 features each
X = randint(1, 100, size=(200, 5))
y = randint(0, 2, size=200)

reg = SVR()
reg.fit(X, y)

y_test = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])    # Input to .predict must be 2-dimensional
reg.predict(y_test)
```

Comment: @Muhammad So, if may answer is the right answer to your question, it would appropriate to accept it as such.

Comment: Thank you @desertnaut for informing , i will be careful onwards

Answer (score -1):

```
# Predicting a new result with Linear Regression
X_test = np.array([[6.5]])
print(lin_reg.predict(X_test))

# Predicting a new result with Polynomial Regression
print(lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X_test)))
```

Comment: This answer doesn't help, because you aren't explaining what the original problem was, or how you have fixed it here